# Is it possible for backbone.js to use a json file as a read-only data store?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-scheme, local-files

I'm working on a project where we'll (hopefully) be using backbone.js to power our web app. The caveat is that it will be run either on a web server (i.e. using `http://` type URLs) or from the local file system (i.e. using `file:///` URLs).

What would be the simplest way to adapt a model object to read files from a local file (i.e. `file:///...`?

Comment: Why would try to run an AJAX app from the local file system? Browsers tend to have all sorts of restrictions on `file://` URLs.

Comment: You can avoid using `file:///` urls by running a light http server locally. e.g. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`. You can then load your static json files using ajax requests.

Comment: @muistooshort we're building it for use online and offline and we don't want to build it twice!

Comment: I think you'll have better luck embedding the data inside the page and skipping the `fetch` and JSON altogether for the offline version.

Answer (score 0):

I face a similar problem in my book: I wanted to configure persistence to use localStorage, but keep the model/collection code the same as when working with a server.

I used the Backbbone.localStorage adapter and wrote a mixin to configure storage on an entity (see https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/commit/3b441c9355ac49348eebb3eca27c06ec79b9f64d) then, in the code I can simply execute the mixin function to configure that model/collection to use localStorage (see line 6 at https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/bcb16d45876c321e071624319bf87c8a9cf1d656/assets/js/entities/contact.js#L6 )

You can get the code using this technique at https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction and the book is available at https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction